# Function App - Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: azure-functions, azure-function-app

I'm using an Azure function - Service Bus queue trigger C#. I'm able to run this function locally fine. I was able to deploy this function app in Azure:

[image]

On running the function:

[image]

I see the following error:

[image]

[image]

How do I resolve this error?

Here is the code:

```
[FunctionName("XFunction")]
public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("xxx", Connection = "queueConnectionString")] Message message, MessageReceiver messagereceiver, ILogger logger)
{
    
    var bodyJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);
    var myMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IdentifiedSubmissionMessage>(bodyJson);

    try
    {
        await _application.ProcessNewSubmission(myMessage.NewSubmissionMessage, myMessage.PackageInformation);
        await messagereceiver.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        
    }
}
```

host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

after updating host.json as shown below, I still the same exception:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "prefetchCount": 100,
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": false,
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 32,
        "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:05:00"
      },
      "sessionHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": false,
        "messageWaitTimeout": "00:00:30",
        "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:55:00",
        "maxConcurrentSessions": 16
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share some more information like: Language, Framework and the binding setup? Especially the binding would be interesting - is this a ServiceBusTrigger?

Comment: Can you show the details error? Seems you are using durable function, can you show the code so that we can do a test.

Comment: Please see the updated question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add `in` bound bindings for these parameters in function.json. Try changing parameter name from `messagereceiver` to `messageReceiver` and update the corresponding binding in function.json.

`MessageReceiver` is used to receive and acknowledge messages from the message container. It is required when `autoComplete` is set to false. Please verify if `autoComplete` is set to false in `host.json`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "serviceBus": {
            "prefetchCount": 100,
            "messageHandlerOptions": {
                "autoComplete": true,
                "maxConcurrentCalls": 32,
                "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:05:00"
            },
            "sessionHandlerOptions": {
                "autoComplete": false,
                "messageWaitTimeout": "00:00:30",
                "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:55:00",
                "maxConcurrentSessions": 16
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! should I set autoComplete to false in messageHandlerOptions & sessionHandlerOptions?

Comment: The error complains about both message & messageReceiver. What could be the issue with message?

Comment: I tried using host.json that you shared and I still see the same error.

Comment: Can you change autoComplete to false at all the places?

Comment: Even after setting authocomplete to false at all places, I still see the same issue.